# The BreakPoint will not currently be hit . no symbols have been loaded for this document

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2008, sharepoint-2007

I am facing the following message while trying to debug my code:

`The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.`

I have VS 2008 and SharePoint 2007.
Whenever I change my code and attach to `w3wp.exe` process I cant hit any breakpoint, although I:

- deployed the built DLLs to the Global Assembly Cache (GAC)
- recycled the IIS Application pool
- restarted the IIS
- restarted my Server
- restarted my IDE (VS)

but unfortunately none of the above solved the issue.

Please advise.

Comment: Make sure you are building your solution in Debug mode rather than release mode

Comment: Thank You Madhur for your response , I checked the solution  , and all DLLs are built in debug mode  .

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions:

1. Delete the solution `.pdb` file and then rebuild the solution - I've sometimes found that this can help when the debugger is not hitting breakpoints.
2. Make sure you attaching to the correct `w3wp` process. I often have 2 or 3 on my dev pc. To be sure just attach to all of them.

Comment: i did all but not yet working for Sharepoint 2010 on VS 2012 update 4

Comment: This did not fix the issue for me either.  I attached all of the w3wp processes.